# Spring Security ExceptionTranslationFilter does't handle thrown in custom filter exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jwt

So I have next Spring Security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter;
private final JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtFilterAuthenticationEntryPoint;
private final AuthzAccessDeniedHandler authzAccessDeniedHandler;

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                    .requestMatchers(USER_PATH + USER_ID_PATH_VAR).authenticated()
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, EVENT_PATH).hasRole("ORGANIZER")
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, TICKET_PATH).authenticated()
                    .requestMatchers(AUTH_PATH + "/logout/{userUuid}").authenticated()
                    .anyRequest().permitAll()
            )
            .sessionManagement(session -> session
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            )
            .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .exceptionHandling(handler -> handler
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(jwtFilterAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                    .accessDeniedHandler(authzAccessDeniedHandler)
            )
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .httpBasic(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .formLogin(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .logout(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
    ;

    return http.build();
}

//other omited code...
```

Here is JWT filter code:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

private final String AUTHZ_HEADER_PREFIX = "Bearer ";

private final JwtService jwtService;

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(
        @NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
        @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
        @NonNull FilterChain filterChain
) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String authzHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

    if (authzHeader == null || !authzHeader.startsWith(AUTHZ_HEADER_PREFIX)) {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
    }

    AccessToken accessToken = jwtService.parseAccessToken(
            authzHeader.substring(AUTHZ_HEADER_PREFIX.length())
    );
    authenticateIfCurrentlyNot(accessToken, request);

    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}

private void authenticateIfCurrentlyNot(AccessToken accessToken, HttpServletRequest request) {
    if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                accessToken.claims().sub(),
                null,
                List.of(convertRoleToSimpleGrantedAuthority(
                        accessToken.claims().role()
                ))
        );
        token.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(token);
    }
}

private SimpleGrantedAuthority convertRoleToSimpleGrantedAuthority(UserRole role) {
    return new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role.name());
}
}
```

Method parseAccessToken() throw custom InvalidTokenException if given coded JWT isn't valid for various reasons. I want to handle this exception for this as you can see in above configuration I've added custom AuthenticationEntryPoint with name  jwtFilterAuthenticationEntryPoint. For now here is code of InvalidTokenException and JwtFilterAuthenticationEntryPoint:

```
public class InvalidTokenException extends AuthenticationException {

public InvalidTokenException(String message) {
    super(message);
}

public static String errorCode() {
    return "invalid.token";
}
}

@Component
@Slf4j
public class JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("handlerExceptionResolver")
private HandlerExceptionResolver resolver;

@Override
public void commence(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        AuthenticationException authException
) {
    log.error(authException.getMessage(), authException);
    resolver.resolveException(request, response, null, authException);
}
}
```

As you can see for ExceptionTranslationFilter to catch my exception I've extended it from AuthenticationException, so as written in official [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/architecture.html#servlet-exceptiontranslationfilter) (ExceptionTranslationFilter pseudocode) it will be able to handle it. But when I try to test exception handling code of commence() method of JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint didn't executed, cause no logs provided:
[image]

So I am looking forward to any help in solving this problem)

Comment: for anyone reading this question in the future. Handing out JWTs to browsers is dangerous and should not be done. That is why there is no such implementation per default in spring security. The code above ignores this fact and builds a home made custom security solution which means this code has some serious vulnerabilities and should not be used in production.

Comment: Would be very grateful if you can suggest some well-explained and from production point secure guide, tutorial or other source of information on securing back-end apps with spring security

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation, the exception is thrown before the `ExceptionTranslationFilter` is invoked due to the statement `addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)` in the `SecurityFilterChain`. Consequently, the `ExceptionTranslationFilter` is not being called.

To explain why the `JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint` is not triggered, the `commence` method of registered `AuthenticationEntryPoint` is typically invoked by the `ExceptionTranslationFilter` when an `AuthenticationException` occurs.

It's important to note that a filter may have its own `AuthenticationEntryPoint`. For instance, in the case of `httpBasic`, authentication is handled by the `BasicAuthenticationFilter`, and any issues result in a call to `BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint`.

I can see 3 options to handle errors in the `JwtAuthenticationFilter`:

#### Option 1:

Execute `JwtAuthenticationFilter` before `AuthorizationFilter` or after `ExceptionTranslationFilter` in the `SecurityFilterChain`.

For instance:

```java
addFilterBefore(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(), AuthorizationFilter.class)
// or
addFilterAfter(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(), ExceptionTranslationFilter.class)
```

#### Option 2:

involves capturing the `AuthenticationException` within the `JwtAuthenticationFilter` and invoking the `commence` method of the `JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint`.

To illustrate this, let's examine how the Spring `BasicAuthenticationFilter` manages the `AuthenticationException`. The `commence` method of the `BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint` is presented below:

```java
@Override
public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
    response.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\"" + this.realmName + "\"");
    response.sendError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.getReasonPhrase());
}
```

Upon inspecting the source code of `BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint`, it becomes apparent that it attempts to handle the `AuthenticationException` and subsequently calls `authenticationEntryPoint.commence(request, response, ex)`.

Applying a similar approach, the following adjustments can be made for the `JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint` and `JwtAuthenticationFilter`:

```java
// JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint
public class JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        log.error("coming to JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint");
        // Sending a custom error code and message
        var errorMessage = """
            {
                "error" : "true",
                "code" : "AUTH-1210",
                "message" : "jwt filter authentication failed"
            }
        """;
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, errorMessage);
    }
}

// JwtAuthenticationFilter
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    public JwtAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint) {
        this.authenticationEntryPoint = authenticationEntryPoint;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            throw new InvalidTokenException("error in JwtAuthenticationFilter");
        } catch (InvalidTokenException e) {
            authenticationEntryPoint.commence(request, response, e);
        }
    }

    private static final class InvalidTokenException extends AuthenticationException {
        public InvalidTokenException(String msg) {
            super(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Update the `SecurityFilterChain` configuration as follows:

```java
.addFilterBefore(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(new JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
```

It's important to note that there is no need to explicitly register `JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint`.

#### Option 3:

Another approach involves handling the `AuthenticationException` directly within the `JwtAuthenticationFilter` and sending the error response. This eliminates the need for `JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint`. Here's the modified `JwtAuthenticationFilter`:

```java
// JwtAuthenticationFilter
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            throw new InvalidTokenException("error in JwtAuthenticationFilter");
        } catch (InvalidTokenException e) {
            var errorMessage = """
                {
                    "error" : "true",
                    "code" : "AUTH-1210",
                    "message" : "jwt filter authentication failed"
                }
            """;
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, errorMessage);
        }
    }

    private static final class InvalidTokenException extends AuthenticationException {
        public InvalidTokenException(String msg) {
            super(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Update the `SecurityFilterChain` configuration:

```java
.addFilterBefore(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
```

Choose the option that best fits your requirements and integrates seamlessly with your authentication flow.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in order of filters. My custom filter was preceding ExceptionTranslationFilter, so when exception was thrown ExceptionTranslationFilter wasn't reached.

This line of code fixed it:

```
.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, AuthorizationFilter.class)
```